# Rendered image different from camera view

Tags: rendering, video

I have done a lot of research into the problem I’m having and I think its tied to the way anamorphic video squeezes pixels, but no matter what I do my anamorphic video clip I’m animating, renders into a standard version of the same aspect ratio.

The image should be 5162 x 2560 at what I think is 1.333 as the pixel ratio. The clip looks fine and the correct width/ height when I am animating it, but when it renders its just a normal image size.

Any help would be greatly greatly appreciated as I have changed so many settings (even at random) and nothing seems to affect the rendering AT ALL.

Thank you.[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens when you set the X Aspect Ratio to 1.0?

Comment: @JeffLange when it's set to 1.0 it comes out the same way. I think its exporting as the aspect ratio not desqueezed, which is how anamorphic footage generally works, but when I desqueeze it, a lot of quality is lost so it makes me think that isn't correct at the same time.